# In the manga title, 「ひのさんのバカ」, why is the の particle used?

Tags: particle-の

Does it mean "Hino-san's idiot" (indicating possession) or "Hino-san *is* an idiot"?

If it's the latter, why shouldn't it be "Hino-san **は** baka"?

Comment: Most likely option 2 in this answer: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/40896/7944

Comment: Dup? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2845/45489

Comment: Also related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/41187/9831

Comment: 「[イワンの馬鹿](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AF%E3%83%B3%E3%81%AE%E3%81%B0%E3%81%8B)」の「の」も、これですよね？　英語で "Ivan the Fool" だし、基本的には同格の「の」では。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possession is just one of the many meanings of の, and does not apply in this case.「ひのさんのバカ」 here means ひのさん**が**バカ, i.e. "Hino is an idiot" (as you suspected).

See: [How does the の work in 「日本人の知らない日本語」?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12825/how-does-the-%E3%81%AE-work-in-%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E4%BA%BA%E3%81%AE%E7%9F%A5%E3%82%89%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E)

While this substitution mostly applies to relative clauses or double-subject constructions (unless there is a direct object marked with を), the subject particle が can be replaced with の in many cases.

Refer also to the Jisho definition for [の](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%AE)

*1. indicates possessive​ (...)*

*2. nominalizes verbs and adjectives​ (...)*

***3. substitutes for "ga"** in subordinate phrases​. (See also が): １００人近くの人がいたが、ほとんど会ったことのない人たちだった。There were almost 100 people, few of whom I had seen before. (...)*

Comment: I agree with this as I think this is the best interpretation in general.  There is also another possible way of looking at things, though: This could also be read as "the idiot who is Hino-san" (Japanese does often have these slight ambiguities in interpretation (which are sometimes deliberately used to add subtle nuances or double-meanings in things like titles, etc, though in this case the ultimate meaning isn't that different, I think))

Comment: Jisho.org ( https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%AE ) って、「同格の『の』」が載ってない！ 「羊のショーン」(Shaun the Sheep)「おさるのジョージ」「イワンの馬鹿」とかの「の」。

Answer (score 6):

The の is appositive (同格). [The Wiktionary entry for の](https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%AE#%E6%A0%BC%E5%8A%A9%E8%A9%9E) may help:

> の
> 助詞
> 格助詞
> 5. 上の語と下の語が**同格**であることを表す。
>
> - 部長の山田さん。
> - 妹の薫さんが来てたよ。 (...)
>
>   1. **悪態をつくときに用いられる表現**。
>
>      - お兄ちゃん**の**バカ。
>      - 部長**の**わからず屋が。

The appositive の has been explained multiple times in this site:

- [What's the difference between 日本人の学生 and 日本の学生 ?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/40892/9831)
- [Confusing use of の](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55540/9831)
- [Translation of Hosutofamiri- no Minasan (ホストファミリーのみなさん)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21463/9831)
- [How would a name be used as a non-restrictive appositive?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18638/9831)
- [が合わせて versus の合わせて](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/77861/9831)

Common/familiar examples:

> 『羊**の**ショーン』 *Shaun the Sheep*
> 『おさる**の**ジョージ』
> 『セロ弾き**の**ゴーシュ』 *Gauche the Cellist*
> 「妹**の**メイです。」
> 「魔女**の**キキです。こっちは黒猫**の**ジジ。」

The Wiktionary page says one of the usages of the appositive の is 悪態をつくときに用いられる.

This has also been asked in this site:

- [What is the role of の in 「お父さんのバカ!」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2845/9831)
- [How does "xxxのオニ" equate to "xxx is bullying/picking on me"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/41184/9831)

Common examples:

> 「メイ**の**ばか！もう知らない！」「お姉ちゃん**の**バカー！」
> 「ばあば**の**ケチ。もうやめなよ。」
> 「クララ**の**弱虫！」
> 「ペーター**の**意地悪。」
> 「おばさん**の**嘘つき！」

Comment: そういえば「馬鹿の太郎がまたミスった」「太郎の馬鹿がまたミスった」は両方言えますね。「太郎の天才が」とは言えないし「太郎の後輩が」だと意味が変わるので、罵る時だけ同格用法の語順が変わりうるんですかね…

Comment: ああー、ホントだ！なるへそですねー！！　（Community wiki にしたので、よかったら加筆してください。最近、落ち着いてSEに向かえてなくて・・）

Comment: うーんでも「のび太さんのエッチ！」は単純な同格では説明つかない気もしてきました（名詞用法の「エッチ」は人そのものを表さないはず）…。「主格の格助詞的なもの」と考えても「同格」と考えても完全には説明しづらいですね…

Comment: あ～確かに形容動詞っぽいですね。「スケベ」なら名詞だったけど。「人+の+名詞or形容動詞」の形で、形容詞は入らないんですね、何でしょうねこれ。。

Answer (score 4):

There are various opinions, but my conclusion is "this construction is hard to explain perfectly based on simpler grammar rules". I can say the following sentences are all valid:

1. 太郎のバカ！
2. 太郎のエッチ！
3. 太郎のバカがまた失敗した。That idiot Taro failed again.

の in Sentence 3 is clearly not a substitution of the subject marker が/は; the subject of this sentence is undoubtedly 太郎のバカ as a whole. However, の in Sentence 2 doesn't seem to be an apposition marker to me. Unlike バカ ("idiot") which is a noun that can represent a person, エッチ is a na-adjective and cannot represent a person. We can say バカが3人いる but not エッチが3人いる.

Therefore, I think it's best to regard this as a special construction that can be used only in the context of abusing someone, like English "You idiot!". "太郎の天才!" is understandable but sounds like a joke to me.